# Android How to: pass and store user Input and return it back to main class(MainActivity)

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I am new to android development, 
    I want to get a user input via **EditText** store it as a String. Pass that string to **c** via **JNI**. When I press a button it that string should be displayed on a **TextView** showing what was typed and the length of the string.
in android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bb1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(
         new Button.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v){
                 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
                 EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ee1);
                 TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);
                 String str =e1.getText().toString();
                 tv.setText(HelloWorld(str)); // This should text
                 t2.setText("This should show length"HelloWorld(l)); //This should show length
             }
         }
    );
}
public native String HelloWorld(String stri);`
```

and in c file:

```
`#include "HelloWorld.h"
 #include <jni.h>
 #include <string.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_james_myapplication_MainActivity_HelloWorld(JNIEnv *env,jobject jobj,jstring jstring1,jint l /* this */) {

const char *str = (*env) ->GetStringUTFChars(env,jstring1,NULL);

return (*env) ->NewStringUTF(env,str);}`
```

I am unable to do show the length of input (I get error 'cannot resolve symbol l'. I'm not sure if I am even doing the code right by this I meant passing the input to c
Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HelloWorld(l)` does not get you the length of a string.  I'm not sure why you thought it would.  To get the length of a string, you call `variablename.length()`.  So here it would be

```
String result = HelloWorld(str);             
tv.setText(result); // This should text
t2.setText("This should show length" + result.length()); //This should show length
```

Comment: Is that right though? I wanted pass the user input after converting it to a string to **C** via **JNI** that is where I want to (in C) to the store the string in c. Calculate the length of it and return the **string** and **length** back to java and display it on **TextView**

Comment: Yes. It passes it to c by calling hello world, then stores the result

Comment: Also, your c leaks memory- you're never calling releasestringutfchars